# Script doesn't work after adding row dynamically

Tags: javascript, html-table, row

I have one function which calculates the total amount.
amount=qty*rate

Here is my html code for showing table

When I add new row it doesn't trigger that calculate function

Can any one help me out?

Here is my script:

```js
   
 function calculate() {
  var myBox1 = document.getElementById('qty').value; 
  var myBox2 = document.getElementById('rate').value;
  var amnt = document.getElementById('amnt'); 
  var myResult = myBox1 * myBox2;
  amnt.value = myResult;
      }
  
  var count = "1";
  function addRow(in_tbl_name)
  {
    var tbody = document.getElementById(in_tbl_name).getElementsByTagName("TBODY")[0];
    // create row
    var row = document.createElement("TR");
    // create table cell 1
    var td1 = document.createElement("TD")
    var strHtml1 = "<INPUT TYPE=\"text\" NAME=\"r_name\" SIZE=\"30\">";
  
   
    td1.innerHTML = strHtml1.replace(/!count!/g,count);
    // create table cell 2
    var td2 = document.createElement("TD")
    var strHtml2 = "<INPUT TYPE=\"text\" NAME=\"r_desc\" PLACEHOLDER=\"description\" SIZE=\"30\">";
    td2.innerHTML = strHtml2.replace(/!count!/g,count);
    // create table cell 3
    var td3 = document.createElement("TD")
    var strHtml3 = "<INPUT TYPE=\"text\" NAME=\"r_qty\" PLACEHOLDER=\"QTY\" ID=\"qty\" ONINPUT=\"calculate()\" SIZE=\"30\">";
    td3.innerHTML = strHtml3.replace(/!count!/g,count);
    // create table cell 4
    var td4 = document.createElement("TD")
    var strHtml4 = "<INPUT TYPE=\"text\" NAME=\"r_RATE\" PLACEHOLDER=\"rate\" ID=\"rate\" ONINPUT=\"calculate()\" SIZE=\"30\">";
    td4.innerHTML = strHtml4.replace(/!count!/g,count);
    // create table cell 5
    var td5 = document.createElement("TD")
    var strHtml5 = "<INPUT TYPE=\"text\" NAME=\"r_total\" PLACEHOLDER=\"amount\" ID=\"amnt\" >";
 
    td5.innerHTML = strHtml5.replace(/!count!/g,count);
  // create table cell 4
    var td6 = document.createElement("TD")
    var strHtml6 = "<INPUT TYPE=\"Button\" CLASS=\"Button\" onClick=\"delRow()\" VALUE=\"Delete Row\">";
 
    td6.innerHTML = strHtml6.replace(/!count!/g,count);
 
    // append data to row
    row.appendChild(td1);
    row.appendChild(td2);
    row.appendChild(td3);
    row.appendChild(td4);
    row.appendChild(td5);
 row.appendChild(td6);
    // add to count variable
    count = parseInt(count) + 1;
    // append row to table
    tbody.appendChild(row);
  }
  function delRow()
  {
    var current = window.event.srcElement;
    //here we will delete the line
    while ( (current = current.parentElement)  && current.tagName !="TR");
         current.parentElement.removeChild(current);
  }
```

```html
<TABLE ID="tblPets" border="1" STYLE="border width:1 orange dashed;background color:#F0E68C;table-row width:2;">
<tr>  
  
            <th><center>Row material Name</center></th> 
   <th><center>Description</center></th> 
            
            <th><center>Qty.</center></th> 
           
            <th><center>Rate</center></th> 
            <th><center>Amount</center></th> 
            <th><center><INPUT TYPE="Button" onClick="addRow('tblPets')" VALUE="Add Row"></center></th>  

   
   
        </tr>  
  <tr>  
  
            <th><center><INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="r_name" SIZE="30"></center></th> 
   <th><center><INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="r_desc" PLACEHOLDER="description" SIZE="30"></center></th> 
            
            <th><center><INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="r_qty" PLACEHOLDER="QTY" ID="qty" ONINPUT="calculate()" SIZE="30"></center></th> 
           
            <th><center><INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="r_RATE" PLACEHOLDER="rate" ID="rate" ONINPUT="calculate()" SIZE="30"></center></th> 
            <th><center><INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="r_total" PLACEHOLDER="amount" ID="amnt" ></center></th> 
            <th><center></center></th>  

   
   
        </tr>
</TABLE>
```

Here is my HTML code

Comment: You're calling `calculate()` only in `oninput` event, not directly in `addRow()` function

Comment: @Martin can you give me detailed solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand now what you wanted to do.

You're using the same element `id` multiple times, so your `calculate()` function always selects only the first inputs in the first row.

I `calculate()` so it takes as a parameter the element that triggered the event and then traverses up the DOM tree to find the closest `<tr>`:

```
var tr = elm;
while ((tr = tr.parentElement) && tr.tagName !== 'TR');
```

Then select input fields only in this table row, calculate what you want and set it as a value to another input field in the same row.

Last thing I changes is that I trigger `oninput` with `oninput=calculate(this)` where `this` is the current DOM element.

```js
   
function calculate(elm) {
    var tr = elm;
    while ((tr = tr.parentElement) && tr.tagName !== 'TR');
    var inputs = tr.querySelectorAll('input');

    var myBox1 = inputs[2].value; 
    var myBox2 = inputs[3].value;
    var myResult = myBox1 * myBox2;
    inputs[4].value = myResult;
}
  
var count = "1";
function addRow(in_tbl_name)
{
    var tbody = document.getElementById(in_tbl_name).getElementsByTagName("TBODY")[0];
    // create row
    var row = document.createElement("TR");
    // create table cell 1
    var td1 = document.createElement("TD")
    var strHtml1 = "<INPUT TYPE=\"text\" NAME=\"r_name\" SIZE=\"30\">";
  
   
    td1.innerHTML = strHtml1.replace(/!count!/g,count);
    // create table cell 2
    var td2 = document.createElement("TD")
    var strHtml2 = "<INPUT TYPE=\"text\" NAME=\"r_desc\" PLACEHOLDER=\"description\" SIZE=\"30\">";
    td2.innerHTML = strHtml2.replace(/!count!/g,count);
    // create table cell 3
    var td3 = document.createElement("TD")
    var strHtml3 = "<INPUT TYPE=\"text\" NAME=\"r_qty\" PLACEHOLDER=\"QTY\" ID=\"qty\" ONINPUT=\"calculate(this)\" SIZE=\"30\">";
    td3.innerHTML = strHtml3.replace(/!count!/g,count);
    // create table cell 4
    var td4 = document.createElement("TD")
    var strHtml4 = "<INPUT TYPE=\"text\" NAME=\"r_RATE\" PLACEHOLDER=\"rate\" ID=\"rate\" ONINPUT=\"calculate(this)\" SIZE=\"30\">";
    td4.innerHTML = strHtml4.replace(/!count!/g,count);
    // create table cell 5
    var td5 = document.createElement("TD")
    var strHtml5 = "<INPUT TYPE=\"text\" NAME=\"r_total\" PLACEHOLDER=\"amount\" ID=\"amnt\" >";
 
    td5.innerHTML = strHtml5.replace(/!count!/g,count);
  // create table cell 4
    var td6 = document.createElement("TD")
    var strHtml6 = "<INPUT TYPE=\"Button\" CLASS=\"Button\" onClick=\"delRow()\" VALUE=\"Delete Row\">";
 
    td6.innerHTML = strHtml6.replace(/!count!/g,count);
 
    // append data to row
    row.appendChild(td1);
    row.appendChild(td2);
    row.appendChild(td3);
    row.appendChild(td4);
    row.appendChild(td5);
 row.appendChild(td6);
    // add to count variable
    count = parseInt(count) + 1;
    // append row to table
    tbody.appendChild(row);
  }
  function delRow()
  {
    var current = window.event.srcElement;
    //here we will delete the line
    while ( (current = current.parentElement)  && current.tagName !="TR");
         current.parentElement.removeChild(current);
  }
```

```html
<TABLE ID="tblPets" border="1" STYLE="border width:1 orange dashed;background color:#F0E68C;table-row width:2;">
<tr>  
  
            <th><center>Row material Name</center></th> 
   <th><center>Description</center></th> 
            
            <th><center>Qty.</center></th> 
           
            <th><center>Rate</center></th> 
            <th><center>Amount</center></th> 
            <th><center><INPUT TYPE="Button" onClick="addRow('tblPets')" VALUE="Add Row"></center></th>  

   
   
        </tr>  
  <tr>  
  
            <th><center><INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="r_name" SIZE="30"></center></th> 
   <th><center><INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="r_desc" PLACEHOLDER="description" SIZE="30"></center></th> 
            
            <th><center><INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="r_qty" PLACEHOLDER="QTY" ID="qty" ONINPUT="calculate(this)" SIZE="30"></center></th> 
           
            <th><center><INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="r_RATE" PLACEHOLDER="rate" ID="rate" ONINPUT="calculate(this)" SIZE="30"></center></th> 
            <th><center><INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="r_total" PLACEHOLDER="amount" ID="amnt" ></center></th> 
            <th><center></center></th>  

   
   
        </tr>
</TABLE>
```

Comment: can u give me script to define html element for                            <select name="i_name[]">
   
             <option >Select</option>
    <?php while ($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($run1)) {
   echo '<option value="'.$row1['itm_name'].'">'.$row1['itm_name'].'</option>';}?>

 
            </select>